# Import of valid bna file into Composer Playground 0.9 fails

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have a business network I've been working with for a few weeks, and the bna file has been deployed successfully to multiple versions of hyperledger fabric.  Suddenly it will not import into composer-playground 0.9, and attempts to run

composer archive create

throw this error:

```
IllegalModelException: Class ApproveMedication is not declared as abstract. It must define an identifying field. File '/Users/dwakeman/git/pharma-network/models/com.ibm.pharma.cto': line 92 column 1, to line 102 column 2.
```

The transaction is defined in my model like this:

```
transaction ApproveMedication {
o String productNdc     
o String proprietaryName
o String nonProprietaryName
o String labelerName    
o String dosageForm     
o String route
o String strength       
o String productTypeName    
o String deaClassification  
}
```

I am running the latest version of composer-cli:

```
composer-cli                   v0.9.0
composer-admin                 v0.9.0
composer-client                v0.9.0
composer-common                v0.9.0
composer-runtime-hlf           v0.9.0
composer-runtime-hlfv1         v0.9.0
```

I know that composer 0.9 introduced some changes in this area, as indicated in the [release notes](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases/tag/v0.9.0):

I have removed the fields as recommended, but it still fails.  Does anybody know what is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out what I was doing wrong.  I recently refactored my business network by following the [Developer Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html) in the Composer documentation.

When you do that and then run

```
npm install
```

to build your application to produce the bna file, it creates a directory in your project folder called node_modules that contains code specific to the business network.  I forgot to delete that code, and that's what was causing my issue.

To solve the problem I deleted the node_modules directory and ran

```
npm install
```

again.  Once I did that I was able to import the generated bna file into [Composer Playground](https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/).